# how to fix error during installation of PyUpdater

Tags: python-3.x, pyupdater

[image: **enter image description here**]

This is the error caused by trying to install PyUpdater.with the `pip install --upgrade PyUpdater` command on `Windows 10`

Comment: Please add you errors on question not screenshots or pics.

Comment: You must install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0

Comment: I have already installed Microsoft Visual C++ 16.3.2. but the problem persists

Comment: Same here, in windows and linux

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.x use:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```